# How to know which button postbacks the page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a problem. When I press "return" key in the text box ASP.NETpage page must do some AJAX operation.It does Ajax operation but it also reloads or postbacks the page.
And now I want to ask:

How can I know which button is clicked?

Thank your for your attention!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   /// <summary>
/// Retrieves the control that caused the postback.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="page"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private Control GetControlThatCausedPostBack()
{
    //initialize a control and set it to null
    Control ctrl = null;

    //get the event target name and find the control
    string ctrlName = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName))
        ctrl = Page.FindControl(ctrlName);

    //return the control to the calling method
    return ctrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a button has a `name` property, that gets passed back with the form data. Ensure each button has a unique name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is talking about the buttons on the keyboard, not html form buttons.

Comment: I am talking about buttons in the page